# Don't understand the use of "n" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iterator, slider

I'm trying to build a Slideshow / Carousel and I found some reference on "https://www.w3schools.com".
The code is very simple and clear but I don't understand the logic in JavaScript, that perimeter "n" drives me nut.
Can someone explain in me what is doing what and the use of that "n"?

(I can't post the question and I need more words)Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint nihil est assumenda nam obcaecati sed, dolorem in aut error nesciunt inventore amet deserunt quisquam quis porro laboriosam eaque perferendis nulla, dicta distinctio magni. Fugit nihil consequatur quam magnam fuga explicabo sapiente in esse, perferendis hic ratione placeat aliquam deserunt aperiam?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://helpx.adobe.com/in/stock/how-to/visual-reverse-image-search/_jcr_content/main-pars/image.img.jpg/visual-reverse-image-search-v2_1000x560.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change `n` to `requestedIndex`. then it will make more sense. `n` simply represents the index of the slide to be shown next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code is:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

#### `plusSlides`

Here's a version of `plusSlides` that might be clearer:

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}
```

If you call it and pass in a number, the function receives that number as the parameter `n`, it:

1. *Adds* that number (`n`) to `slideIndex` (which is a variable the function closes over), saving the result in `slideIndex`; and
2. Calls `showSlides` with the result (the value just stored in `slideIndex`

So for instance, if `slideIndex` is 2 and you pass 1 into `plusSlides`, it sets `slideIndex` to 3 (its old value, 2, plus 1) and shows the slide at index 3.

#### `currentSlide`

The perhaps-clearer version of `currentSlide` is:

```
function currentSlide(n) {
  slideIndex = n;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}
```

If you call `currentSlide` with a number, it receives the number as `n` and

1. *Sets* `slideIndex` to that number; and
2. Calls `showSlides` with the result

So for instance, if `slideIndex` is 2 and you pass 1 into `currentSlide`, it sets `slideIndex` to 1 (*replacing* its old value) and shows the slide at index 1.

Answer (score 1):

`n` passed to each function is nothing but the **parameter** passed to that respective function,

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

In above two functions `n` is a parameter passed to it.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Here you can see you are passing 1, 2, 3 values to `currentSlide()` functions. n will hold values which you pass to the function. Here it will be 1 or 2 or 3.